# cocoa app integrating with linked in cocoa app OSX mac (not iOS)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, oauth, linkedin-api

i need to integrate linked-in with  cocoa app. send invitations to linked-in contact list from my app please help me in doing it. registered my app in linked-in developers got the app key secret key..etc
problem with how to use OAuth help me friends... i used this one https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client but not able to do help me friends. i am new to cocoa programming